# Reading a binary file as text and manipulating it... [C#] Versus [VB.NET]

Tags: c#, vb.net, file, file-io, binaryfiles

Well guys I am in a bit of a pickle here...

I am doing some exercises on encrypting data. One of them are binary files. I am currently using triple DES to encrypt and decrypt the files both in VB.NET and C#...

Now the thing is, once it is decrypted in VB.NET and saved, i can execute it again...

But for some reason, my C# file is bigger! 20,4K where VB.NET one is 19,0. The C# file also is rendered unexecutable...

Upon a closer look. The files appear almost exactly the same, but C# seems to add in a few extra bytes here and there in (seemingly) random places...

I am currently using File.ReadAllText(String filepath, Encoding encoding); with UTF-8 encoding

thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a small snippet of code and an example of a 'changed' set of data would help spur some assistance.

Comment: Can you post both VB.NET and C# implementation of encryption/decryption? They are probably subtly different.

Comment: SImplify your encryption code and put in here otherwise impossible to spot the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you're using `File.ReadAllText`... but also that these are *binary* files. That makes me suggest that you're treating opaque binary data (e.g. the result of encryption) as if it were text (e.g. calling `Encoding.GetString` on it).

*Don't do that.*

Basically, encryption generally works on binary data - binary in, binary out. If you need to encrypt text to text, you'll usually apply a "normal" encoding to convert the text to binary data (e.g. `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)`) and then use Base64 to convert the opaque binary data to text in a lossless way - e.g. with `Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)`.

Decrypting is just the reverse: use `Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText)` to get the encrypted binary data, decrypt it, and then use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted)` to get back to the text.